# PHPMyadmin SQL large table export deleting records

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I am trying to export a table from my database. Its a large table (>500MB). However, after exporting it I found out that there are some records that are missing. What could be causing this problem? There is no error message or anything during the process, everything seems fine except that some records are missing.

I am using phpMyAdmin version 4.0.10.7 and the data was exported in `.csv` format. 
Also the resulting csv file is 510,2MB. (Maybe this is an upper limit for a default export).

Comment: How did you go about verifying that they are missing? Did you do a `SELECT COUNT(*)` on the table before export and again after re-importing it? If records are missing, reimport it to the _same_database, then issue a `LEFT JOIN` query between the old table and new one to figure out which records are missing so you can identify a pattern.

Comment: need to provide more details.

Comment: I use the data to output a JSON through my own API. I saw a null value whereas the other version (using the old database) did not have a null value. I can see that the records missing are the ones inserted LAST.